# Why my rake db:migrate throws error message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing Rails v2.3 application.

When I run "rake db:migrate" I got the following error message:

```
rake/rdoctask is deprecated.  Use rdoc/task instead (in RDoc 2.4.2+)
rake aborted!
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

What is the reason?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like your MySQL credentials are not set correctly in `config/database.yml`.

Comment: Do you mean the username and password?

Comment: Yes. Take a look at the [Configuring a Database](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#configuring-a-database) section in the Getting Started guide.

Comment: I corrected my database credentials, then I got a new error "rake/rdoctask is deprecated.  Use rdoc/task instead (in RDoc 2.4.2+)", what could be the reason for this?

Comment: A quick googling revealed the answer to that one: http://matthew.mceachen.us/blog/howto-fix-rake-rdoctask-is-deprecated-use-rdoc-task-instead-1169.html